# Beamer missing section causing Undefined control sequence error

Tags: beamer, errors

I ran onto this error today, here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}
% \section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Cursed frame}
This is awkward.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The compilation gives: `Undefined control sequence. [\end{frame}]`
Apparently declaring a subsection without a section causes the error to appear as removing the comment, makes the error go way.

What also is weird is that despite the error, the `.pdf` is produced fine in both cases.
I'd like to know why this happens, as in other documents having subsections without section never was a problem. Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As **Joseph Wright** has mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170944/beamer-missing-section-causing-undefined-control-sequence-error/170950#comment393866_170950), the fact that sectional units have to be appropriately nested is a design choice made by Till Tantau.

The "culprit" of the error you got can be found in the following lines of the definition of `\beamer@subsection` (given in `beamerbasesection.sty`) used by `\subsection`:

```
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{3}{toc}%
```

Using the original definition and commenting out the mentioned lines, suppresses the error:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@subsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionentry{\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsection}}%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}%
    }%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \edef\subsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    %\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{3}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Cursed frame}
This is awkward.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but this, of course, it's not advisable since it will mess up the bookmarks.

Another way of preventing the error is to load the `bookmark` package:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
% \section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Cursed frame}
This is awkward.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, the best thing to do is not to use a subsection without a previous section (using a subsection without section doesn't make much sense, anyways).

Comment: Indeed: Till's attitude on this sort of thing is quite clear if you read the code. Sections are only really supported by `beamer` if properly nested, and while `\subsubsection` is defined it's not really fully implemented as Till didn't want people to use it!

Comment: @JosephWright in some minutes I'll add some remarks along the lines of your comment to my answer.

Comment: I think that this covers my question thank you. Indeed it does not make sense using subsections without sections in `beamer`. I arrived at the situation because I commented out part of my slides to avoid compilation.

Comment: @VagelisBebelis I've added some new information to my answer that could be of interest for you.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, now my question is completely answered! Thanks once more.